# JSHint - Indent to bracket

Tags: indentation, jshint

I have my JSHint configured to validate indentation in my code. Here's rule `indent: 4`

This rule warns places where I have indentation to bracket. How do I get this fixed?

Here's the code that I am referring to

```
slug            :   {
                        type: String,
                        required: true,
                        unique: true
                    }
```

Here's the error:

```
[L12:C29] W015: Expected 'type' to have an indentation at 9 instead at 29.
```

Can you please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jshint's indent is useful for catching syntax error type mistakes people might make not coding or realizing something is a part of the block / statement about:

```
if (foo)
bar();
```

here, `bar` executes only when `foo` is truthy. To fix your error above, 
you'd want the second line to only indent 4 characters (see below). You can also disable this feature with `indent:false` if your style is more to align keys / colons to other properties.

```
slug : {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
}
```